# Unable to find WPF User Controls in Visual Studio C# 2008; stuck with nonexistant Control instead

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, elementhost

This is a rather unusual question but here's the issue:

I have a WPF control created in Visual Studio C# 2008, map.xaml, created in the project Remote.

I want to add this to a Windows Form, also in Remote, using the ElementHost tool. Simple, right?

I created the ElementHost, went to select the HostedContent, but the only choice available is UserControl1.xaml, which is a file I created when testing in Remote earlier. This file, however, was completely deleted after I had finished with it. I have searched my entire system and the project and can find no references to it.

I would appreciate it greatly if anyone has any ideas as to why this might be happening; I just want to add map.xaml, but VS is refusing to recognise anything except this ghost file.

Thanks,

M

Comment: And what (kind) is your Map Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Map Control should be public, for starters.

And make sure you rebuild the lib, and reference the correct build/version.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that much to my embarrassment I worked out the problem right before I checked this again; typical as always that I spend the day trying to work this out then get it *after* I ask the question! Thank you very much for your assistance anyway.